# What does a Purescript `data` type with no constructor mean?

Tags: types, purescript

For example (from purescript-halogen):

```
data Slot (query :: Type -> Type) output slot
```

Is that declaring an uninhabited type? (If so, I would assume it would be useful exclusively as a phantom type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably should be a `foreign data` rather than just `data`, as this one is inhabited - it only comes into use through coercion though, as it's used as a version of another type with some of its parameters existentially hidden.

Comment: So normally it would be an uninhabited type? (And perhaps we're lucky the compiler didn't optimize away "unreachable" code.)

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'm not sure that, even if the compiler was better, there'd be anything to optimise away though - `Slot` only exists in the type system, so there's nothing at the term level to remove!